# How to set spacing between font when using drawText

Tags: android

I am currently writing a custom TextView to draw text.

Here is the code:

```
canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, p);
```

But i can't find any api in `Canvas` or `Paint` the define a spacing between font. So how can i set different font spacing for different lines of text.